# Show index Url on htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I have, this code in htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex boot.php
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule pick.dll boot.php
```

So in the url of my website, I don't see the pick.dll and the boot.dll I don't see nothing, why?..why htaccess hide files who have the code:

```
DirectoryIndex boot.php
```

And how I can solve this problem, to show url?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show `boot.php` in browser URL then use rewrite rule with `R` flag:

```
DirectoryIndex boot.php

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^pick\.dll$ /boot.php [L,R]
```

Comment: This method doens't work, and the url continue hidden!

Comment: What happens when you try to open `http://domain.com/boot.php` does `boot.php` remain OR go away?

Comment: when i put it www.mysite.com/boot.php, the url continue in boot.php, so when I open in this url www.mysite.com/ the url don't show nothing only www.mysite.com

Comment: when i open, the url goes to boot.php and the page goes to 404 not found

Comment: ok rename your .htaccess to something else and then try opening `http://domain.com/boot.php`

Comment: Didn't understand why you need to rename the boot.php?